# Selection based on value from PHP MySQL table with JavaScript value

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm trying to have a select box with a value that shows based on if the database has a "yes" or "no" in the column. I cannot figure out what my error is in my syntax, but this will not work. I am using JavaScript values to fill all of my table.

```
tbl +='<td ><select name="status"><option'+if (val['Col4'] == "yes"): + 'selected>yes</option><option'+if (val['Col4'] == "no"): +'selected>no</option></select></td>';
```

Here is my table:

```
tbl +='<tr row_id="'+row_id+'" style="background color:'+val['default_color']+'">';
tbl +='<td ><div col_name="Col1">'+val['Col1']+'</div </td>';
tbl +='<td ><div col_name="Col2">'+val['Col2']+'</div></td>';
tbl +='<td ><div col_name="Col3">'+val['Col3']+'</div></td>';
tbl +='<td ><select name="status"><option'+if (val['Col4'] == "yes"): + 'selected>yes</option><option'+if (val['Col4'] == "no"): +'selected>no</option></select></td>';                     
tbl +='<td >;
tbl +='</tr>';
```

But my table crashes.
The PHP is working for all the other parts of the table. It's getting through an ajax request and then saving the value.

So `val['Col4']` will work as a text input, but not as a select box selection.

Comment: What is the expected result? What is the actual result? Where is the PHP code?

Comment: why is this a php/mysql question? there isn't any code to support the tags.

Comment: My table crashes. The php is working for all the other parts of the table. It's getting it through an ajax request and then saving the value. So val['Col4'] will work as a text input but not as a select box selection.

Comment: You're making a `<select>` with just one option. Is that really what you want? Or do you want both yes and no options, with the one that matches `val['Col4']` pre-selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a conditional (aka "tertiary") expression. You need to add both options, not a single option with a conditional in it. Then each option conditionally adds `selected`.

```
tbl +='<td ><select name="status">';
tbl += '<option' + (val['Col4'] == "yes" ? ' selected' : '') + '>yes</option>';
tbl += '<option' + (val['Col4'] == "no" ? ' selected' : '') + '>no</option>';
tbl += '</select></td>';
```

You were also missing a space between `option` and `selected`.

Comment: This works! But I am trying to let the user select the other option on the dropdown as well. When I use these versions I am only getting the value of the original column in the database. How do I allow it to have the other value as well?

Comment: That's the question I asked in my comment above. There's nothing in your code that creates multiple options, it just creates a single option with conditional contents.

Comment: Oh my bad sorry. I had thought I could conditionally allow it to be selected within the select box with the options yes and no.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfect!